# Is there a method to close and Reconnect an app in Xamarin Android UITest?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uitest

Is there any way to close and reconnect to my app in Xamarin UITest?

In my test case I want close and reconnect my Android app.

Comment: I was actually able to do this without a back-door and while keeping the test running: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63322161/2353336

Answer (score 3):

Depending upon what you mean by "close", but here are a couple of ways...

In the `MainActivty` of your `Xamarin.Forms` Android app, add some `UITest` backdoors:

```
[Export("HardExitBackdoor")]
public void HardExitBackdoor()
{
    Log.Info("UITest", "Finish");
    Finish();
}

[Export("BackgroundBackdoor")]
public void BackgroundBackdoor()
{
    Log.Info("UITest", "MoveTaskToBack");
    MoveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

Now in your test, you can "exit" your app and "restart" it:

```
[Test]
public void HardRestartApp()
{
    app.Invoke("HardExitBackdoor");
    BeforeEachTest();
    WelcomeTextIsDisplayed();
}

[Test]
public void BackgroundedApp()
{
    app.Invoke("BackgroundBackdoor");
    BeforeEachTest();
    WelcomeTextIsDisplayed();
}

[Test]
public void SoftRestartApp()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        app.Back();
    BeforeEachTest();
    WelcomeTextIsDisplayed();
}
```

#### Update:

**Android/Java and Calabash/Ruby**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ~~~~
    public void HardExitBackdoor() {
        Log.w(TAG, "finish");
        finish();
    }
    ~~~~
}
```

To invoke this method in Ruby/calabash-android:

```
backdoor "HardExitBackdoor"
```

Comment: My android app is not developed using Xamarin, so i can't write the above mentioned function(HardExitBackdoor) in my app's product code. Can't we do this using test FWK alone?

Comment: @user3446142 I added Java/Ruby example to my answer since you are not using C#

Comment: Thanks Sushil for the update. But my App is developed using script sharp, I have not used Xamarin(whether it is C# or Calabash) at all to develop my App. So I can't add the above code to my product code. I want to do this close and reconnect using Xamarin UI Test FWK. Can you please help me on this.

Comment: @user3446142 You would need to ask the "script sharp" developers on how to exit their app environment (assuming it is a web view shell) since you are not using C# or Java. If they provide some exported API for doing so, you should be able to call it via a C#/UITest (or Calabash/Ruby) backdoor invoke.