# Xamarin.uitest how to close app instance

Tags: xamarin.uitest

How to close and relaunch app in Xamarin.UI Test ? I want to restart app for each scenario in feature .

Platform: android

There is no quit() or close() session methods like we have in appium.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a method to close and Reconnect an app in Xamarin Android UITest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38099395/is-there-a-method-to-close-and-reconnect-an-app-in-xamarin-android-uitest)

Comment: That doesn't answer my Question.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `ConfigureApp.Android.StartApp()` in your test will launch a new session of your application for you to interact with (just make sure to save the new object).

However, with the use of NUnit, methods tagged with `[Setup]` will run automatically before every method tagged with`[Test]`. That means *most* test suites only use the `ConfigureApp.Android.StartApp()` method once, in `[Setup]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use `Xamarin.UITest.ConfigureApp.Android.StartApp(AppDataMode.DoNotClear)` in your test. It will close the app and restart it without clearing the app's data, all while the test keeps running.

This is a cross-platform solution; you can use `Xamarin.UITest.ConfigureApp.iOS.StartApp...` too.

Answer (score 0):

Given you are on your are using Xamarin UI Test project,

You can use `Finish()` to close the application,

or

`MoveTaskToBack(true)` to minimize the application.

So that you can call them from your Test.cs, you'll need to write myBackdoorClose and myBackdoorMinimize functions (since `Finish()` and `MoveTaskToBack(true)` are only available in the App.cs context). How to do that, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38099395/is-there-a-method-to-close-and-reconnect-an-app-in-xamarin-android-uitest)!